# How to hide something at the telestation?

Tags: geocaching

I've tried to find a few caches, where the coordinates were showing the T-Mobile telestation, such like that:
[image]

I'm used to not being able to find geocache (I'm not enough experienced, or maybe simple I don't have good enough perception), but this case doesn't give me rest - I just couldn't figure any movable parts here, where something can be placed without risking damaging the machine or triggering alert.

Is there any 'standard' place to hide in such machines? I don't know any cacher around to ask for a tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is one of the standard hiding place in German cities ;o).
You should inspect the foot-rest (which is plastic btw, but a film container fits into it perfectly)...

Comment: Is there a footrest on my photo? I'm not sure what part do you have in mind... Have you maybe some example photo? ;)

Comment: The grey "tray" a bit below knee height. The thing you would naturally use if you want to tie your shoes.

Comment: I didn't know that's for placing foot on them ;) Next time I'll look there.

Comment: OK I haven't found any cache but I've checked one of those telestations. There's nice place on the bottom of that foot-rest.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what sort of cache it is, and how big it is. I presume it is some sort of 'micro' or 'nano' cache.

One popular type for these is a screwtop magnetic container, eg [Nano Cache Container](http://shop.geocaching.com/default/cache-essentials/cache-containers/nano-cache-container.html). These are only about 1cm diameter and height, and often silver or black. So if stuck onto something metal, it can be hardly noticeable. It might just look like a bolt head.

I'm not familiar with that sort of telephone booth, but from the photo it looks like there is plenty of metal surface. So a magnetic container could be stuck on any of that, maybe underneath something. Also, it may look like a bolt, so it might help to feel around, and see if anything moves.

Comment: Well, every place I've inspected is quite exposed in that telepohones...